# Resolving multiple promises in 1 http request

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, promise

My current implementation have multiple controllers accessing the same JSON dataset using a service. I want to be able to resolve multiple requests that comes in **during an ongoing HTTP request**, in a single query.

### Service:

```js
app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q) {
  var promises = [];
  var busy = false;
  return {
    getData: function() {
      if (busy) {
        var p = $q.defer();
        promises.push(p);
        return p.promise;
      }
      busy = true;
      var promise = $http.get('data.json').then(function(response) {
        while (promises.length > 0) {
          promises.pop().resolve(response.data);
        }
        busy = false;
        return response.data;
      }, function(error) {
        while (promises.length > 0) {
          promises.pop().reject(error);
        }
        busy = false;
      });
      return promise;
    }
  }
});
```

### Controller:

```js
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, dataService) {
   $scope.logger = "";

   function getIt(a) {
     dataService.getData().then(function(d) {
      $scope.logger += 'Request '+a+': '+(new Date).getTime()+'\n';
   });
   }

   // These will be resolved in a 'batch'
   getIt(1);
   setTimeout(function(){getIt(2)},100);
   setTimeout(function(){getIt(3)},0);

   // This will be resolved in the 'next batch'
   setTimeout(function(){getIt(4)},2000);
   setTimeout(function(){getIt(5)},2100);

});
```

A [plunker](http://plnkr.co/6zmZSe5NWn9signSyEiy) example.

Assuming the sequence of the request is not important, is there a better way to do this or are there any flaws that might lurk in this technique?

Comment: any particular reason for doing this, won't the request already be cached in the browser?

Comment: Sorry for not being thorough, my application actually does not request for a static JSON, but a live data feed that gets requested from an angular broadcast through cordova's push plugin. The example shown is just for clarity in the specific implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually need multiple promises here. You can just give out the same promise to each caller during the same turn:

```
app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q) {
  var busyPromise = null;
  return {
    getData: function() {
      if (!busyPromise) {
        busyPromise = $http.get('data.json').finally(function() {
          busyPromise = null;
        });
      }
      return busyPromise;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Never knew promises can be shared. This definitely simplify things, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you can have as many handlers on a promise as you want - they all will receive the same value. (You only shouldn't have 0 error handlers)

Comment: Is `.finally()` available?

Comment: @Roamer-1888: The [angular $q docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) mention it briefly. Apparently it's new in 1.2, not available in 1.0, and named `.always` in 1.1.

Comment: Things change quickly. Last time I looked $q had `.then()` and nothing else. BTW: nice answer.

Comment: Yeah, looks like they migrated towards ES6… It's new to me as well, but I regularly have to check the docs of the particular used lib when answering, and it was just there :-)

Answer (score 1):

the code looks ok, but I think `defer` is deprecated, alse beware of the `.then(success, fail)` anti-pattern, for example, you are throwing error for all the waiting promises, it would be hidden for the actual one making the call. So I would change it to something like:

```
app.factory('dataService', function($http, $q) {
  var promises = [];
  var busy = false;
  return {
    getData: function() {
      if (busy) return new Promise((res, rej) => promises.push({res, rej}));
      busy = true;
      return $http.get('data.json').then(response => {
        promises.forEach( promise => promise.res(response.data));
        promises = [];
        busy = false;
      }).catch( e => {
        promises.forEach( promise => promise.rej(e));
        promises = [];
        busy = false;
        throw e;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!